# How to read text file in C without fopen

Tags: c, text, fopen, getchar

> can anyone help me? I need to read a file called address.txt and work
>   with each word in there (I have one word per line to make it simple).
>
> **I am forbidden to use these functions:**
>
> *Malloc, freee, fopen, fclose, fscanf,... qsort, lsearch, bsearch a hsearch*   I think the teacher wants us to use getchar, argv, argc or
>   something like that.
>
> Let's say the name of the program is test.c
>   ____ /test.c < address.txt
>
> If I write this as an argument when starting the program, I should be
>   able to work with the text file. Any tips how to extract the data
>   stored in address.txt? I have tried several times without success :/
>   Only fopen worked for me.

**EDIT: Everything I did was fine, Code::Blocks editing program caused the problems. I tried it in Linux terminal and it worked perfectly! :)**

Comment: what have you tried so far? please add a [mcve] so we can see where you're going wrong.

Comment: You may want to have a look at manuals of `read (2)`, `open (2)`, `write (2)`. The way you handle data inside all depends of the way it was stored.

Comment: When you use input redirection, it will be `stdin` that is redirected.

Comment: Also the same question: [Read text file in C without fopen, fclose, fscanf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46828573/2371524).

Answer (score 1):

Well yes, if your program is started like this:

```
$ ./test < address.txt
```

Then (assuming a compliant OS but this is fairly standard across major desktop systems) your program will start with a `stdin` stream connected to the contents of the file `address.txt`.

So you can use [`getchar()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) to read from it, and find the words.

Note that you won't be starting the C file, you must compile it first.

Comment: Thanks :D Code::blocks caused the problems, in Linux it works fine.